# perl: variable requires explicit package name error?

Tags: perl

I have this function: Its supposed to just print through a custom linked list:

```
sub myprint {
    my $iter = shift->{top};
    my $refType = ref($iter);
    while ($refType -ne "SCALAR") { #44
        print $iter->{data};
        $iter=$iter->{prev}; 
        $refType = ref($iter);
    }
}
```

errors:

```
jddancks@GIGABYTE-SERVER:/media/20B9-BF25/perl/OOP$ perl test_linked_list.pl
syntax error at cs351/linked_list/MyLinkedList.pm line 44, near "-ne"
Global symbol "$iter" requires explicit package name at cs351/linked_list/MyLinkedList.pm line 46.
Global symbol "$iter" requires explicit package name at cs351/linked_list/MyLinkedList.pm line 46.
Global symbol "$refType" requires explicit package name at cs351/linked_list/MyLinkedList.pm line 47.
Global symbol "$iter" requires explicit package name at cs351/linked_list/MyLinkedList.pm line 47.
syntax error at cs351/linked_list/MyLinkedList.pm line 48, near "}"
Compilation failed in require at test_linked_list.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test_linked_list.pl line 3.
```

Comment: I just tried running a test program with this function commented out. It ran without errors.

Comment: `-ne` doesn't do what you think it does. Perl doesn't have `-` as a prefix for string comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never trust an error that comes *after* a syntax error.

On line 44, `-ne` is an error, it should be `ne` (you were probably thinking shell rather than perl).

Fix that, and the other errors will go away, or at least you will be left with another error that you can trust and do something about.